# Why isn't my Parallax scrolling JavaScript code working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, parallax.js

I started designing my own site and followed a YouTube video tutorial on how to code Motion Parallax scrolling on Dreamweaver using JavaScript and CSS so I followed the video and did everything it told me to but my code is still not working?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cF3oyFXjRWk

I feel like my JavaScript code is not linked or something because some of the syntax or variables that are highlighted in a specific color on the video are not highlighted for me. What could my problem be?

I put the JavaScript within the head tag as well... this is the .js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ypos, image;
    function parallex () {

        ypos = window.pageYOffset;
        image = document.getElementById('background');
        image.style.top = ypos * .4 + 'px';
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', parallex);

    </script>
```

This is all my code with the css as well....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="../Tezel's Website/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">




    <style type="text/css">
    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

    #image{
        position: relative; 
        z-index: -1
    }


    #content{
        height: 750px; 
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: -10px;
        background-color:#4dbbac;
        position: relative; 
        z-index: 1; 
    }

    </style>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    var ypos, image;
    function parallex () {

        ypos = window.pageYOffset;
        image = document.getElementById('background');
        image.style.top = ypos * .4 + 'px';
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', parallex);

    </script>



  </head>


  <body>




  <img id = "background" src = "sky1.jpg" width = "100%" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Tezel's Website/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class = "main">
    <div id = "container">

    <div class = "header">




    <div id = "content"> 
    </div> 




    </div>

    </div>    
    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not looking quite charming:

`<script src="../Tezel's Website/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Check if all resources are loaded. Right click and check element or inspect element in your browser. Make sure all resources are found and loaded.

Comment: Hey so I basically started a new HTML file without the bootstrap or anything but still it is not working....

Comment: have you checked resources if are loaded.. or do you have any error in console?

Comment: Hmmm I changed the name to '<script src="../tez/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>' which opens when I press control D so the sources are fine but I solved the error :) Thanks though anyway I still learnt new things because of you!